# How do I track the hours of my laptop usage?

Tags: laptop, software-rec, logging

I'm a new laptop user, and I'm looking for a piece of software that will give me the number of hours I have been using my laptop on a daily, weekly and monthly basis.

Any help regarding this? I have searched the web with the necessary keywords and have found nothing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This may not exactly be what you're looking for but hard drives keep track of their number of power ons as well as their running time. You can use CrystalDiskInfo to monitor how much time your hard drive has has power. http://crystalmark.info/software/CrystalDiskInfo/index-e.html

Only flaw with this is if you get a new hard drive.

[image]

Comment: what happens if i get a new hard drive?

Comment: When you look at CrystalDiskInfo, it will show the stats for the new drive instead of the life of both the old drive plus the new one. You're basically keeping track of your laptop's life and usage by the life and usage of the hard drive. New Hard Drive = New Counter.

Comment: i have installed it and all seems fine except that for me its shows a temperature of 37 degrees is it fine?

Comment: 37 isn't horrible for a primary drive. However, I wouldn't like seeing it get much more over that. It is a laptop afterall. They don't have the best airflow.

Answer (score 0):

I know absolutely nothing about this but it was listed as an answer in another place I saw, maybe there are some comments that will help.
http://www.manictime.com/